# Should Compaction within gc_grace_seconds Preserve Tombstones?

Tags: java, cassandra

If I delete a row (creating a tombstone), and run a major compaction within `gc_grace_seconds`, would one expect the tombstone to survive at least until `gc_grace_seconds` has elapsed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the tombstone is expected to survive for gc_grace_seconds. The reason is that if a node is down at the point in time you delete the row, the delete must have a chance to get propagated to that node later on. When the node is back online and you run `nodetool repair` it can pick up the delete. If you do not run the repair within gc_grace_seconds then your deleted record might return from the dead.

IFF you are running a single-node cluster, then you can safely set gc_grace_seconds to 0. As there are no other nodes that might be missing deletes.

Have a look at this page on [Cassandra operations](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Frequency_of_nodetool_repair), repair, and gc_grace_seconds.

Comment: Thanks - we think we found a bug in Cassandra where tombstones are not preserved when a table is truncated.

Comment: I would say that is by design and not a bug. Truncating a table physically removes the SSTable files. So there is no way a tombstone could be written to them. And due to the complete lack of data there is also no process that would propagate this to other nodes of the cluster.

Comment: This also happens when deleting the last of the data from a table. If you deleted all rows from a table whilst a node was down, and then that node came back up, it would resurrect all data in that table. IMO the SSTable structure should be such that tombstones can persist even when nothing else in the table does to prevent the above situation.

Comment: So you are saying that the SSTable files get deleted if you delete all data from a table (not truncating the table)? I guess that would indeed be a bug. What Cassandra version are you running?

Comment: We're using 2.0.5. We're trying to write an RSpec test that will reproduce the issue, and then hopefully we'll raise an issue in JIRA.

Comment: Looks like the bug was fixed in 2.0.7